# Navigating to separate page/component in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I have created a new module called as login-page. I want navigate to that module from app.component.html

Then link is given through a button in `app.component.html` is as follows:

```html
<a routerLink="/login-page">
  <button class="ms-Button" id="btn-1">
    <span class="ms-Button-label" id="Sign_up_btn">SignUp</span>
  </button>
</a>
```

The `app.modules.ts` file looks like this:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './login-page/login-page.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SignupFormComponent } from './signup-form/signup- form.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginPageComponent,
    SignupFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [

    BrowserModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'login-page', component: LoginPageComponent },
      { path: 'signup-form', component: SignupFormComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It's navigating fine, but its content(`login-page.component.html`) is displaying in same page(`app.component.html`). I want it to in display separate page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AppComponent** is the major component and other components are rendered inside it.
So what you have to do is remove content from the Appcomponent and add those content to a component under another route.
Then by default call that route and when required navigate to **login** route from there.

Then your code will be like follows,

**AppModule**

```
   .... 
   RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'initial-page' },
    { path: 'initial-page', component: InitialPageComponent }, // move all your appcomponent code to this component
    { path: 'login-page', component: LoginPageComponent },
    { path: 'signup-form', component: SignupFormComponent }
   ])
   ....
```

**InitialPageComponent.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['../login-page']">
        <button class="ms-Button" id="btn-1">
             <span class="ms-Button-label" id="Sign_up_btn">SignUp</span>
       </button>
</a>
```

**AppComponent (html)**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Also plese read the [DOCS](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: Means i need to create separate router.ts file  then need to call route??

Comment: [routerLink]="['../login-page']"

Comment: Sorry to ask this, Means i need to create one more component(initial-page) and i need to move my code(app.component.html) to there. I am really confused about this angular routing..

Comment: Yeah. Thats exactly what you have to do

Comment: Also change the router link as this -  [routerLink]="['../login-page']"

Comment: then <router-outlet></router-outlet> has to be  present in (app.component.html) or i want to remove that also?

Comment: only  <router-outlet></router-outlet> has to be present in (app.component.html).

Comment: Thanks for your patience,i will do it now.

Answer (score 2):

The setup is easy like this

1. put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside the tempate of app
   component this where the component realted to route reander
2. Your routes

   ```
   { path: 'login-page', component: LoginPageComponent },
   { path: 'signup-form', component: SignupFormComponent } , 
   { path :'',redirectTo:'login-page',pathMatch:'full'} // defualt route
   ```

Hope it work.

Comment: <router-outlet></router-outlet> its already there in(app.component.html) & i have tried giving path like u mentioned still it doesn't work.